# WP Admin Login keeps redirecting to login

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, login, password

Everytime I try to login it keeps redirecting me to the login page, or pretty much just loops.  No error messages, just redirects.  If I reset the password it works, but the next time it starts all over again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Too little information to guess. Please try to debug for additional info, [Better HTTP Redirects](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-http-redirects/) plugin is staple for looking into redirect issues.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something with cookies. Try to clear your cookies in your browser and test again. If you can login after that, try to disable all plugins and enable the default WordPress-theme and successive enable your plugins to isolate the problem.

Or it can be your .htaccess-file:

Follow these easy steps and you’ll get your WordPress Blog and Admin Access Back:

1. Backup your .htaccess file on your hard drive
2. Delete the .htaccess file from the root of your server
3. Go to your blog’s admin panel and log-in
4. On the left sidebar, go to Settings –> General and changes your
   WordPress Address and Blog Address to include www (so it should be
   http://www.domainname.com instead of http://domainname.com).
5. Save Settings
6. Take your .htaccess backup and reupload it to the root of your
   server

Answer (score 0):

I see the thread is too old. but still can help somebody else.
I came through this problem and this is what I did:

1. in the address bar, I removed everything after wp-login.php and hit ENTER
2. I typed my credentials
3. voila, I am seeing wordpress dashboard

Comment: Glad that worked, although that may not solve this for everyone and it would be useful to work out what's causing the redirect loop in the first place too.